What evidence supports Calypso's island being Gozo (Malta)?
In the Odyssey, the island where Calypso lives is called Ogygia, but what real Mediterranean island is this? One long-standing theory has it as Gozo, the second island of Malta:

Ogygia or Phaeacia has been associated with the putative sunken Atlantis. A long-standing tradition begun by Euhemerus in the late 4th century BC and supported by Callimachus, endorsed by modern Maltese tradition, identifies Ogygia with the island of Gozo, the second largest island in the Maltese archipelago.

I can confirm that this theory is endorsed by modern Maltese tradition, but what is the evidence for it? Gozo is very far west of both Troy and Ithaca, and there are other theories ranging from Egypt to the mid-Atlantic, with modern Greek tradition (naturally) claiming Ogygia as one of the Greek islands. Why would Gozo make sense as a location for Calypso's island?

Strabo said that it was Callimachus who identified Ogygia with Gozo, but he thought the idea ridiculous:

Some allowance might be made for others, but no manner of excuse can be put forward for Callimachus, who pretends to the character of a critic, and yet supposes that Gaudus [Gozo] was the island of Calypso, and identifies Scheria [Phaeacia] with Corcyra [Corfu].†
Strabo (1st century CE). Geography 7.3.6. Translated by H. C. Hamilton (1854). Project Gutenberg.
† The translator comments in a footnote, “It seems more probable that Callimachus intended the island of Corsura, now Pantalaria, a small island between Africa and Sicily”. However, I’m inclined to trust Strabo here, because Pantelleria is west of Gozo, whereas Homer indicated that Phaeacia is east of Ogygia, as discussed below.

Unfortunately Callimachus’ text has been lost, so that we do not know his reasons for making this identification. However, Homer says that Odysseus sailed his raft east (keeping Ursa Major on his left) from Calypso’s island for seventeen days before landing on Phaeacia:

Gladly then did goodly Odysseus spread his sail to the breeze; and he sat and guided his raft skilfully with the steering-oar, nor did sleep fall upon his eyelids, as he watched the Pleiads, and late-setting Bootes, and the Bear, which men also call the Wain, which ever circles where it is and watches Orion, and alone has no part in the baths of Ocean. For this star Calypso, the beautiful goddess, had bidden him to keep on the left hand as he sailed over the sea. For seventeen days then he sailed over the sea, and on the eighteenth appeared the shadowy mountains of the land of the Phaeacians, where it lay nearest to him; and it shewed like unto a shield in the misty deep.
Homer. Odyssey 5.269–281. Translated by A. T. Murray (1919). Perseus Digital Library.

So if Callimachus had started by identifying Phaeacia with Corfu, then Ogygia would need to be a small island several hundred miles west of Corfu, and there are not many candidates in this part of the Mediterranean.
Strabo, by contrast, thought that Homer had placed Ogygia in the Atlantic Ocean, adducing several passages in support of his argument:

Such are the sentiments of Polybius; and in many respects they are correct enough; but when he discusses the voyage beyond the ocean, and enters on minute calculations of the proportion borne by the distance to the number of days, he is greatly mistaken. He alleges perpetually the words of the poet,

Nine days by cruel storms thence was I borne; [Odyssey 9.82]

but at the same time he takes no notice of this expression, which is his as well,

And now borne sea-ward from the river stream
Of the Oceanus; [Odyssey 12.1]

and this,

In the island of Ogygia, the centre of the sea, [Odyssey 1.50]

and that the daughter of Atlas [Calypso] dwells there. And the following concerning the Phæacians,

Remote amid the billowy deep, we hold
Our dwelling, utmost of all human kind,
And free from mixture with a foreign race. [Odyssey 6.204]

These passages clearly refer to the Atlantic Ocean, but though so plainly expressed, Polybius slily manages to overlook them.
Strabo 1.2.18.

However, it ought to be clear to any reader of the Odyssey that when the narrative is set in Greece or the Aegean, the presentation is realistic, but the further the characters journey, the more fantastic the descriptions and events become. Thus the journey of Telemachus to the court of Menelaus in books 2–3, overnight by ship from Ithaca to Pylos and then two days overland by chariot to Sparta, is realistic, but when Menelaus describes his voyage to Egypt, he encounters the shape-changing Proteus, and when Odysseus describes his wanderings, he meets cyclopes and sea-monsters and so on. Thus the islands of Circe, Calypso, the cyclopes, the Phaeacians etc. are fictions or “traveller’s tales” and we should not expect them to correspond to any real places.
This point was made by Eratosthenes in the 3rd century BCE, who wrote, according to Strabo:

that Homer and the rest of the ancients were well versed in every thing that related to Greece, but were in a state of considerable ignorance as to places at a distance, in consequence of the impossibility of their making long journeys by land or voyages by sea. In support of this he asserts, that Homer designated Aulis as ‘rocky,’ as indeed it is; Eteonus as ‘mountainous and woody,’ Thisbe as ‘abounding in doves,’ Haliartus as ‘grassy;’ but that neither Homer nor the others were familiar with localities far off; for although there are forty rivers which discharge themselves into the Black Sea, he makes no mention whatever even of the most considerable, as the Danube, the Don, the Dnieper, the Bog, the Phasz, the Termeh, the Kizil-Irmak, nor does he even allude to the Scythians, but makes up fables about certain illustrious Hippemolgi, Galactophagi, and Abii. He had become acquainted with the Paphlagonians of the interior from the relations of such as had penetrated into those regions on foot, but he was perfectly unacquainted with the sea-coasts of the country; which indeed was likely enough, for that sea was in his time closed to navigation, and known by the name of Pontus Axenus [or the Inhospitable] on account of the severity of the storms to which it was subject, as well as of the savage disposition of the nations who inhabited its shores, but more especially of the Scythian hordes, who made a practice of sacrificing strangers, devouring their flesh, and using their skulls for drinking-cups; although at a subsequent period, when the Ionians had established cities along its shores, it was called by the name of Pontus Euxinus [or the Hospitable]. He was likewise in ignorance as to the natural peculiarities of Egypt and Libya, as the risings of the Nile, and the alluvial deposits, which he no where notices, nor yet the isthmus [of Suez] which separates the Red Sea from the Egyptian Sea; nor yet does he relate any particulars of Arabia, Ethiopia, or the Ocean
Strabo 7.3.6.

Strabo quoted Eratosthenes in order to disagree with him, but to the modern reader it’s clear that Eratosthenes was right.
